# Unity C# Char Level System Multiple Scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to add a level up system to my game, the level system works within the gameplay scene. However, I have multiple scenes. How could I add a level up scene where the player chooses what skills to level up, which carries through the scenes. Would I need to make the level system static?

Answer (score 2):

You can use DontDestroyOnLoad Method to carry Objects between scenes, this way you can ensure that the Player object, or the object which contains your player data go to another scene filled with previous info.

Se more on [Unity API Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PlayerPrefs` to save your levels in mutiple scenes. You simply assign a value in your level up scene and access the value while loading the new one.

`PlayerPrefs.GetInt(string key)` gets the value of the variable in 'key'.

`PlayerPrefs.SetInt(string key, int value)` stores 'value' in the variable in 'key'

**Level Up**

```
// Access the previous value
int speed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Speed");

// Increment the value
speed++;

/// Store the value
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Speed", speed);
```

**Load Level**

```
void Start
{
    // Load stats
    int speed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Speed");
    int strength = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Strength");
    int health = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Health");
    int stamina = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Stamina");
}
```

Comment: I have a save and load file that I read and write to for a lil more added protection and such. I don't really understand the implementation of it and how I can use it keep the char level, xp, so on and so forth throughout every scene. Would I need to load on enter and save on exit for every scene?

Comment: @RyanW I don't really know how save and load files work. The method that I showed you works between scenes and doesn't need to be saved. However, when you close the game you might lose all of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your level variable a `static` variable which makes it a universal value across all scripts/scenes. I think that is what's best for you.
`PlayerPrefs` aren't bad however, you might you need to `PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey` and reapply the new and update the old. Too complicated, use static variables.

Take a look at this Unity link - https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/statics

Clarifies exactly what I'm trying to say but more elaborated upon.

Answer (score 0):

For my game I used an extra "overlay scene" containing a GameManager (singleton) which is used to load and unload "level scenes". To keep the Overlay scene, I use [LoadSceneMode.Additive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html) in the LoadScene() method. For unloading you might want to use [UnloadSceneAsync()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync.html) so that the unloading process is split into multiple frames. That way no prefabs are needed for things that are in nearly every level (which sounds a lot like your "level up" panel thing).